# DateFormatter Issues - Show Current Date and Time

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdateformatter

I am trying to display a time in such format

> Your Order was Placed on 1 January 2014 at 11:30am

This is my code but I just can't get it working

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
todaysDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
date.text = todaysDate;
```

I am close with it currently showing "03 July 2014 02:56"

How can I add the "Your order was placed" and the "at" ? and also how can I get it to be just 3 July instead of 03 July?

Thanks

Comment: Since you are displaying this to the user, why use a fixed format? Why not use a more natural, locale specific format so the date and time appear in the style expected by the user?

Comment: It's for homework, I need to have it display like that but I just don't know how to

Comment: "'Your order was placed on' d MMMM yyyy 'at' hh:mma"

Comment: When I put the "Your Order Was Placed On" and the "at" into the text it changes the whole label text to something similar to "7AM43"

Comment: @BrownEye The text needs to be inside single quotes.

Comment: Note the single quotes around literal text.  Also note that HH was changed to hh for 12-hour time, and "a" was added to specify that am/pm should be generated.

Comment: More than you ever wanted to know about date format patterns is found [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  It's a good one to bookmark if you will be dealing with date formats very much.